# How To Use get_posts & get_the_post_thumbnail Outside The Loop

Tags: get-posts

This works fine within the loop but i cannot hook it outside the loop.

```
global $post;
$args = array( 'post__in' => array( 1, 5, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, ) ); 
$thumbnails = get_posts($args);
foreach ( $thumbnails as $thumbnail ) {
    if ( has_post_thumbnail( $thumbnail->ID ) ) {
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $thumbnail->ID ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $thumbnail->post_title ) . '">';
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $thumbnail->ID, 'thumbnail' );
        echo '</a>';
    }
}
```

I've tried dozens of variations using get_posts and WP_Query.

Edit: Added an array of specific post I.D's

Comment: I don't see any reason why the posted code wouldn't work outside the loop. It works for me. Can you elaborate a little what "it doesn't work" means? What `global $post` does in that code?

Comment: Switch to `WP_Query` and then do `echo $thumbnails->request` and check what SQL query is generated from the query

Comment: It works when using a shortcode in a widget outside the loop but not when i hook the function in directly.

Comment: Where are you trying to hook this, which hook are you using then. I suspect you have the wrong hook, one that is running to early

Comment: Tried wp_head and loop_start.

Comment: I have tested your code hooked to `wp_head` and `loop_start` and it works fine. Have you tried one of the bundled themes. Does it work in a bundled theme with no plugins. Have you cleared caches in order to eliminate that. Have you considered a corrupt Wordpress installation (core files)

Comment: Yes, the PHP works but the jQuery and CSS don't outside the loop unless i include the function in a shortcode and use a text widget.